# Swift Timer not restart when back to the view

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, timer

i want to check if my timer is still running or not, because when i leave the view and return i wanted the timer still running not reset. i try this and its still failed

```
if otpViewModel.timer == nil {
        otpViewModel.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(onTimerFires), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }else if otpViewModel.timer != nil {
        otpViewModel.timer?.invalidate()
        otpViewModel.timer = nil
        countDownLabel.isHidden = true
        resendButton.isHidden = false
    }

 @objc func onTimerFires()
{
    otpViewModel.timeLeft -= 1
    //resendBtn.isHidden = true
    if otpViewModel.timeLeft <= 0 {
        if otpViewModel.minutes == 1 {
            otpViewModel.minutes = 0
            otpViewModel.timeLeft = 60
        }
        else {
            otpViewModel.timer?.invalidate()
            otpViewModel.timer = nil
            countDownLabel.isHidden = true
            resendButton.isHidden = false
        }
    }
    if otpViewModel.minutes == 1 {
        switch otpViewModel.otpMethod {
        case .SMS:
            countDownLabel.text = "SMS dikirim ulang dalam \(otpViewModel.minutes) : \(otpViewModel.timeLeft) detik"
        case .WHATSAPP:
            countDownLabel.text = "WhatsApp dikirim ulang dalam \(otpViewModel.minutes) : \(otpViewModel.timeLeft) detik"
        default:
            print("none")
        }
    } else {
        switch otpViewModel.otpMethod {
        case .SMS:
            countDownLabel.text = "SMS dikirim ulang dalam \(otpViewModel.minutes) : \(otpViewModel.timeLeft) detik"
        case .WHATSAPP:
            countDownLabel.text = "WhatsApp dikirim ulang dalam \(otpViewModel.minutes) : \(otpViewModel.timeLeft) detik"
        default:
            print("none")
        }
    }
}
```

i try this and still not working, my timer keep getting reset whenever i leave the view and return to the view

Comment: `}else if otpViewModel.timer != nil {` just do `} else {`

Comment: Use `Date` to save the current date and time when the current view controller leaves.

Comment: @aheze i dont understand what do you mean by "just do" on my else if?

Comment: @afipermana replace `}else if otpViewModel.timer != nil {` with `} else {`. They will both be the same, because before you're doing `if otpViewModel.timer == nil { ...`. But that's just a general suggestion - your problem is probably somewhere else.

Comment: @aheze yeah still not working mate

Comment: @ElTomato im sorry can you show me what do you mean by saving the timer with Date?

Comment: "my timer keep getting reset whenever i leave the view and return to the view"  You are not showing that part.

Comment: @ElTomato i think its because i put my Timer.scheduleTimer
on my viewdidload and i wanna overcome with with a simple condition where if the timer still run i dont wanna do the Timer.scheduleTimer

Comment: Nobody sees your `viewDidLoad` method.  Why don't you find out the purpose of the `viewDidLoad` method?

Comment: i already know the viewDidLoad method....so whats your point? can you just please show how to "Use Date to save the current date and time when the current view controller leaves"? otherwise thanks for bothering me

Answer (score 1):

I guess the timer just gets reset when you are leaving your view controller because you setting you timer in your `viewDidLoad` and once you leave your `ViewController`, everything will be cleared from the memory. Then when you opening the `ViewController` again, it gets loaded to the memory, once you leave the `ViewController` everything is cleared up again.